# To click javascript modal dialog popup using WATIR

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, watir

When I am closing my IE browser I get the popup message - "stay on this page or leave this page". This seems to be a javascript modal dialog box.

How to access the buttons "Stay on this page" and "Leave this page" through WATIR?

Comment: This might help: http://watirwebdriver.com/javascript-dialogs/

Answer (score 0):

The browser object has a `windows` instance method I think. You should be able to select it based off the title or perhaps the body text